# SQL Select throwing exception, saying Data doesn't exist

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle

```
    STSQL = "select STOCKROOM_QTY from mpcs.si_mtipart_info where inv_type = '" & rsMPCS("inv_type") & "' and mti_part_no = '" & rsMPCS("mti_part_no") & "'"
    rsMPCS2 = MPCS_SELECT_SQL(UCase(STSQL))
    If rsMPCS2.HasRows Then
        Dim CurrentQuan As Long = rsMPCS2("STOCKROOM_QTY")

        STSQL = "update mpcs.si_mtipart_info set STOCKROOM_QTY = " & (CurrentQuan - NumericUpDown1.Value) & " where inv_type = '" & rsMPCS("inv_type") & "' and mti_part_no = '" & rsMPCS("mti_part_no") & "'"
        MPCS_UPDATE_SQL(UCase(STSQL))
```

The above code is part of a from that is changing the STOCKROOM_QTY on an Oracle table.

The error I am getting is [image]

However if I run the select statement it is sending `select STOCKROOM_QTY from mpcs.si_mtipart_info where inv_type = MACH_PART' and mti_part_no = '01400010005'`

You can see it exist.

[image]

No reason to down vote because you don't like the way it was done.  I researched it, made it as clear as possible (even gave pictures) which took effort as well.  And without any further info someone was able to easily see the problem.

Comment: First of all Possible SQL Injection.

Comment: Your error is 'No Data exists for the row/column' not that your column doesn;t exist

Comment: Ok I typed it wrong, but data does exist none the less right?  And lad2025, I know I'm going through and fixing these things eventually, right now its an internal app only no access to the outside but I inherited this code so in time.

Comment: Why check if there are rows to update before updating, instead of just doing the update? If there are no rows to update, that's not going to matter overall.

Comment: You apply a UCase(STSQL) but your Oracle instance is case sensitive or insensitive?

Comment: There are reasons, but regardless the next line would still be `Dim CurrentQuan As Long = rsMPCS2("STOCKROOM_QTY")` which is what is throwing the error.

Comment: Joe, the ucase is fine, is used throughout the application.

Comment: As I stated before, this application was 90% written (not by me).  I inherited the responsibility of just making it work with a tight deadline.  Between projects I'll rewrite things properly.  However dealing with it as it stands, I simply cannot figure out why it says there is no data when clearly there is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are using a data reader.  In that case, you must call its `Read` method before accessing any data.

Comment: Its always the little things, great eye Jmcilhinney, that's all it was.  Silly I missed that.  Thank you.